# Self-Join of Subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have two datasets, Flights Delay and Airport Codes.
Flights Delay dataset includes these columns: OriginAirportID and 
DestAirportID.

Airport Code dataset has 4 cols: airport_id, city, state and name. 
I wrote the following query to join the two datasets:

```
select OriginAirportID, DestAirportID, name as DestName, city as DestCity, state as DestState
FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
ON t1.[DestAirportID] = t2.[airport_id];
```

Then, I got one single dataset. But actually, I am trying to get the 
airport_id, name and city fields for OriginAirportID too.
Then, I have tried a self-join query to extract the data.

```
select Origin.DestName AS OriginName, Dest.DestName AS DestName, 
Dest.OriginAirportID, DestAirportID, DestCity, DestState
FROM t1 AS Dest
INNER JOIN t1 AS Origin
ON Origin.OriginAirportID = Dest.DestAirportID;
```

But actually, I got some combinations between each destination and 
arrivals locations. Then, I used some subquery but I do not get the expected 
result.

```
select OriginAirportID, DestAirportID, DestName, DestCity
FROM t1 AS DEST01
WHERE DestName = 
  (SELECT DestName FROM t1 AS DEST02
  WHERE DEST01.OriginAirportID = DEST02.OriginAirportID);
```

Comment: I got lost in the question myself. Example data from the tables and desired result would help a lot. But if I understood right, what you could do is `SELECT columns FROM flights_delay JOIN airport_codes origin ON origin.id = flights_delay.origin_id JOIN airport_codes dest ON dest.id = flights_delay.dest_id`. This way, you will get the origin and destination airport for each delay row.

Comment: It took me a while to find out the right syntax since I use AzureML. But then, I came up with a query that works beautifully! Thank you so much, Viliam. I could have spent day figuring out how to do that without your help..